# Writing to file but file is empty

Tags: c#

I am writing my output to this file but it keeps showing empty in the Organized.txt. If I change the last foreach loop from sr2.WriteLine and only write to the console with WriteLine then the output displays properly on console so why isn't it displaying properly in the textfile?

```
 class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

            string[] arr1 = new string[200];


            System.IO.StreamWriter sr2 = new System.IO.StreamWriter("OrganizedVersion.txt");




                    // Dictionary, key is number from the list and the associated value is the number of times the key is found
                    Dictionary<string, int> occurrences = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                    // Loop test data
                    foreach (string value in File.ReadLines("newWorkSheet.txt"))
                    {
                        if (occurrences.ContainsKey(value)) // Check if we have found this key before
                        {
                            // Key exists. Add number of occurrences for this key by one
                            occurrences[value]++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // This is a new key so add it. Number 1 indicates that this key has been found one time
                            occurrences.Add(value, 1);
                        }
                    }
                    // Dump result
                    foreach (string key in occurrences.Keys)
                    {
                        sr2.WriteLine(key.ToString() + occurrences[key].ToString());
                    }               

                   Console.ReadLine();



        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't find any `Organized.txt` in your code

Comment: `flush` the output buffer or `close` the stream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either wrap the code in a `using` to ensure the stream is closed.

```
        using(StreamWriter sr2 = new StreamWriter("OrganizedVersion.txt"))
        {
           ....
        }
```

Or you can `flush` or `close` after writing.

```
 sr2.close();
```

Comment: that is SOOOO strange! Just a minute ago I had that in my code and it still didnt work but I reput that sr2.Close() in my code and then saved the document and now it is working.

Comment: If you are debugging, and stop the debugger then C# doesn't flush the buffers. Even if you are inside a using when you're debugging. That's why if you have streams open for long periods you should flush them after any important data is sent (i.e. writing to a log file).

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're *actually* writing to `OrganizedVersion.txt`

Looks like @Mathew is also pointing out that you haven't closed/flushed your buffer.

Try a `using` statement as follows:

Replace:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter sr2 = new System.IO.StreamWriter("OrganizedVersion.txt");
```

With:

```
using (var sr2 = new System.IO.StreamWriter("OrganizedVersion.txt"))
{
    // Your other code...
}
```

Comment: I suspect that's a copy-paste error. I *hope* that's a copy-paste error.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I hope you're right.  If that's not the problem, I also would rather Matthew get his credit for this answer...

Comment: lol, that's ok. I'd rather get points on the harder questions. :)

Comment: @MathewFoscarini nah, every valid answer helps someone out.

Comment: It was a copy paste error but not in this question but when I was copy pasting my code to clean some parts out...